# DateTime problems

Tags: sql-server, model-view-controller, datetime

After spending few hours and get frustrated I'm decided to ask for help here, so please answer :)
In MSSQL 2008 I have two fields with datetime data type Created and Updated
Created field have getdate() default value, both are not nulls.
Now, in my mvc controller when I'm creating new data I'm passing current date with 
`model.Created = DateTime.UtcNow;` On next line I'm passing whole object to domain model with

```
viewModel.ToDomain(model);
```

I have viewModel which looks like this

```
ViewModel ToDomain(model myModel)
{
  myModel.Id = Id;
  myModel.Created = Created;
  myModel.Updated = DateTime.Utc.Now;
}
```

Now I want first time on create action to Created and Updated field be populated with current datetime, but on edit action just Updated field to be populated, Created field should remain intact.

Any further info on request.
Regards

Comment: Hey, you can have separate edit action and try MVC ajax to call that action you can do what you mentioned i.e. updated field should be populated and created remain intact. Try this - http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/contact-manager/iteration-7-add-ajax-functionality-cs ; let me know if it works; will set this as an answer.

Comment: nice link, thank you. Very helpful.

Comment: No worries, let me how it goes, Cheers!

Comment: When using MVC you probably ought to be aware of whether you're loading an existing database record or creating a new one based on the query string of the page. Routing allows you to specify an action on your controller based on the url match. In that way, when editing an object you should be able to load it from the database and then update the Updated property whilst leaving the Created date unaltered.